# View xml request in SOAP call

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio-2008, soap, compact-framework

I'm trying to debug some problems we have with a web service, and would like to view the xml used in the SOAP call.

Anyone who know how I can do this in visual studio 2008?

I'm developing on windows mobile 6 using compact framework 3.5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to view the traffic (including the packet contents - i.e. the XML) to and from the service.

Answer (score 2):

Place a breakpoint in your code before the XML is returned by the web service.  Then, when the breakpoint is hit, you can use VS' built-in XML visualizer to view the data.

Comment: Please don't use comments to ask a question on an unrelated, 9-year old answer. This should be an entirely new question...